# I am using prepared statements to make a SQL request in PHP but I am getting an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been trying to figure this out for about four hours. I've searched every corner of the internet and can't seem to figure this out. The error I'm receiving is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? TO ?' at line 1" This is happening at the  mysqli_stmt_prepare line.

I also tried

$sql = "ALTER TABLE orders CHANGE ? ? varchar(50);";

but that didn't help either.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
if(isset($_POST['newField']) && isset($_POST['oldField'])){
      $pst_New_Field_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['newField']);
      $pst_Old_Field_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['oldField']);

      $sql = "ALTER TABLE orders CHANGE ? ? varchar(50)";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

      if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        echo "SQL statement prepare failed";
        echo mysqli_error($link);
      }else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $pst_Old_Field_Name, $pst_New_Field_Name);
          if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            "order could not be changed " . mysqli_error($link);
          }else{
              echo "<p class='fieldSuccess'>Order successfully changed</p>";
          }
      }
  }else{
    echo "fields not set";
  }
```

Comment: What does the call to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` return?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: On additional inspection it turns out you're trying to bind column names, which you can't do with `mysqli`. Why are these dynamic? You can only use placeholders for values, not entity names like tables or columns.

Comment: @kmoser Nothing, is it supposed to? I don’t think that’s the issue because the problem occurs before reaching that line.

Comment: @tadman I’ll look into using OOP instead of procedural, hopefully it won’t be too hard to switch over. 

As far as binding column names, what does care about what I’m binding? They’re all variables as far as it knows no? 

I’m making an app that allows users to customize their table.

Comment: @lefkos What do you mean "nothing"? That function returns a Boolean, as described in the documentation.

Comment: It's really super simple in the case of `mysqli`, as in `$stmt->bind_param(...)` instead of `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, ...)` and so on. The pattern is `f($x, ...)` generally becomes `$x->f(...)` instead.

Comment: @kmoser so you’re saying I should run a check to make sure the bind statement executed correctly before proceeding? Sorry I’m not seeing what you’re getting at.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I’ll try OOP and cross my fingers.

Comment: If you're adding column names, keep in mind that's really very risky, especially if you're opening it up to untrusted users. You'll need to [escape identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) differently, you can't use prepared statements for that. Be very careful when allowing this sort of activity.

Comment: This is a strange thing to want to do, and may point to a flaw in your schema design

Comment: I figured out it's because my identifiers have spaces in them since I tried one that is a single word and it worked. I have now tried many different ways to use an identifier with spaces but I still can't seem to get it to work. I know MySQL wants identifiers with spaces to be in backticks but for some reason I can't escape the backticks, single quotes or double quotes using the backslash for some reason, it'll escape 3 but not all 4.

$sql = "ALTER TABLE orders CHANGE /'Order Numbers/' /'ORDER NUMBERS/' varchar(50);";

Comment: @lefkos Yes, you should test whether the bind statement returned `true` or `false` and if `false` then you have a problem.

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`